# RestKit crashes after upgrading to 0.10.0

Tags: iphone, objective-c, restkit

I seem to be able to start restkit just fine and load objects using the traditional loadobjectsatresourcepath: delegate: method.  However, when I introduce the block:^{}, restkit crashes every time.

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] loadObjectsAtResourcePath:@"/api/v1/places" delegate:self block:^(RKObjectLoader* loader) {
    loader.objectMapping = [[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider objectMappingForClass:[Place class]];
}];
```

I get this in the log:

```
2012-05-12 19:07:32.266 App - [RKObjectManagerloadObjectsAtResourcePath:delegate:block:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3aa2e0
2012-05-12 19:07:32.268 App - *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
reason: '-[RKObjectManager   loadObjectsAtResourcePath:delegate:block:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3aa2e0'
```

Any thoughts on how to resolve this issue?  THanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception tells you exactly what the problem is: `RKObjectManager` does not respond to `loadObjectsAtResourcePath:delegate:block:`. A quick glance at the API documentation reveals that [the original method](http://restkit.org/api/0.9.3/Classes/RKObjectManager.html#//api/name/loadObjectsAtResourcePath%3adelegate%3ablock%3a) no longer exists in 0.10.0, and seems to have been replaced with [loadObjectsAtResourcePath:usingBlock:](http://restkit.org/api/0.10.0/Classes/RKObjectManager.html#//api/name/loadObjectsAtResourcePath%3ausingBlock%3a).

You should be able to avoid the exception by using the new method:

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] loadObjectsAtResourcePath:@"/api/v1/places" usingBlock:^(RKObjectLoader* loader) {
    loader.objectMapping = [[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider objectMappingForClass:[Place class]];
}];
```

Comment: Thanks! Thats what I suspected. this was so confusing for me and then I found out that Xcode was linking against an old Restkit library and my code completion was not working right.  After deleting my derived data contents and rebuilding, everything works right.